# Using Eclipse to interface with GitHub for non-supported language

Tags: git, eclipse, version-control, energyplus

I use Git via Eclipse for source control on my Python and Javascript projects and find it really useful. I also use a piece of building energy simulation software, EnergyPlus and would like to use Git and Eclipse for managing input files for this. There is no plugin available for EnergyPlus specifically but is there a generic "file editing" perspective that I could use? I'm not concerned about launching the code from Eclipse, just in using a familiar interface for GitHub which can track the incremental changes made when editing simulation input files.

The answer to this question may also be useful for people using Git to version control on text documents, or on any other language which does not yet have a plugin like PyDev.

Comment: When it comes to tooling, SO is the better choice for such questions.  On Meta.Programmers.SE there is a question/answer combo for [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) which addresses the various types of questions that git gets and where they go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Resource` perspective which provides you with the `Project Explorer`, `Outline` and `Tasks` views.

Use `New > Project > General > Project` to create projects which are not specific to a language.

You might want to use `Preferences > General > Content Types` and `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations` to define which editor is used for the files you create.